# Changing text of span inside element not working using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the text of a span. Inside a dropzone element. The problem is when I want to do it globally like this:

```
$('.resolutie').text(obj[0].dpi + 'DPI');
```

It works fine (but is not what I want because it changes all classes when there are multiple elements). But if I try this:

```
$(this).next('.resolutie').text(obj[0].dpi + 'DPI');
```

It stops working. I've tried multiple things. These too:

```
$(this).find('.resolutie').text(obj[0].dpi + 'DPI');
$(this).next('.resolutie').text(obj[0].dpi + 'DPI');
$(this + '.resolutie').text(obj[0].dpi + 'DPI');
```

But none of these work.

My code is inside a dropzone so my total code looks like this:

```
$('.dropzone').each(function(index){
    $maxfiles = $(this).attr('maxfiles'); <<<< this works, so why not the rest with $(this) ?
    $(this).dropzone({
        paramName: 'postedFile',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictDefaultMessage: 'Sleep je bestand(en)',
        dictRemoveFile: 'Verwijder',
        dictCancelUpload: 'Annuleren',
        dictInvalidFileType: 'Dit type bestand is niet toegestaan',
        dictCancelUploadConfirmation: 'Weet je zeker dat je het uploaden wilt annuleren?',
        dictMaxFilesExceeded: 'Maximale aantal bestanden overschreden',
        maxFiles: $maxfiles,
        acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .tif, .tiff',
        thumbnailWidth: '150',
        thumbnailHeight: '120',
        thumbnailMethod: 'crop',
        previewTemplate: $(".hiddendiv").html(),
        // File contains dropzone file object, response contains ajax response from php file
        success: function (file, response) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            $(this).next('.resolutie').text(obj[0].dpi + 'DPI');
        },
    })
});
```

This is the entire HTML markup if that is helpful:

```
<form action="upload/uploaden.php" class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-started dz-max-files-reached" maxfiles="1" id="dropzone4">
   <input type="hidden" value="Monomeer" name="productnaam">
   <input type="hidden" value="Twan" name="klantnaam">
   <input type="hidden" value="20" name="hoogte">
   <input type="hidden" value="20" name="breedte">
   <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Sleep je bestand(en)</span></div>
   <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-complete">
      <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="Untitled-4.jpg"></div>
      <div class="dz-details">
         <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>0.1</strong> MB</span></div>
         <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">Untitled-4.jpg</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress="" style="width: 100%;"></span></div>
      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>
      <span class="toewijzen">Aantal toewijzen</span>
      <div class="uploadcontent">
         <input type="text" class="fileinput">
         <button class="plusminupload" id="minupload">−</button>
         <button class="plusminupload" id="plusupload">+</button>
      </div>
      <hr class="uploadline">
      <span class="infoline"><span class="infospan resolutie">Resolutie:</span> <i class="fas fa-check-circle goedgekeurd"></i></span>
      <span class="infoline"><span class="infospan formaat">Formaat:</span> <i class="fas fa-times-circle afgekeurd"></i></span>
      <button class="yellowbtn btn vrijgevenbtn" type="button">Bestand vrijgeven</button>
      <a class="dz-remove" href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove="">Verwijder</a>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: please, try to create a [mcve], try to exclude from code the parts that are not relevant to solve your question, to avoid "polution" of the code, which makes harder to understand and find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `this` inside `function` , so there `this` is not your object, but the function itself. try to set `var $this = this` in the outer function, then in the success function use `$this.find('resolutie')`

```
$('.dropzone').each(function(index){
    $maxfiles = $(this).attr('maxfiles'); <<<< this works, so why not the rest with 
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this) ?
    $(this).dropzone({
        paramName: 'postedFile',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictDefaultMessage: 'Sleep je bestand(en)',
        dictRemoveFile: 'Verwijder',
        dictCancelUpload: 'Annuleren',
        dictInvalidFileType: 'Dit type bestand is niet toegestaan',
        dictCancelUploadConfirmation: 'Weet je zeker dat je het uploaden wilt annuleren?',
        dictMaxFilesExceeded: 'Maximale aantal bestanden overschreden',
        maxFiles: $maxfiles,
        acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .tif, .tiff',
        thumbnailWidth: '150',
        thumbnailHeight: '120',
        thumbnailMethod: 'crop',
        previewTemplate: $(".hiddendiv").html(),
        // File contains dropzone file object, response contains ajax response from php file
        success: function (file, response) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            $this.find('.resolutie').text(obj[0].dpi + 'DPI');
        },
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but if I add multiple files in the dropzone all get updated. Is there a way to only update the preview of the last uploaded file.

Comment: `$this.find('.resolutie').last().text(obj[0].dpi + 'DPI');`